# Where to find the Canon CAPT Driver?

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

Canon CAPT Driver v2.4 was to be download from a link posted [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CanonCaptDrv190#Ubuntu_12.04_Install%29), but when I write this the link is dead.

I had the driver and have uploaded it [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B35PbjeIaccqSjdnYUtyaFU1Rm8/edit?usp=sharing).

But I suppose the driver and even a newer version should be available. Is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of the Canon CAPT Driver for Linux is version <s>2.5</s> 2.7.1 You can find information about the driver at the [Canon CAPT Printer Driver for Linux Version 2.xx](http://support-sg.canon-asia.com/contents/SG/EN/0100459601.html) webpage.  Click the **Download** button to download the driver.

The instructions for installing the Canon CAPT Driver v2.6 in Ubuntu 14.04 are found at the [Ubuntu Canon Capt Driver wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CanonCaptDrv190) under the **Ubuntu 14.04 Install** heading.