# Are Ubuntu 16.04 & 18.04 compatible with Canon MG3650

Tags: compatibility

Are Ubuntu 16.04 & 18.04 compatible with Canon MG3650 all in one printer, or suggestions please

Comment: It should be but what does the manufacturer say? Instead of posting a question you should be googling.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to find the Canon CAPT Driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294783/where-to-find-the-canon-capt-driver) (PIXMA MG3670)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Drivers are [here.](https://en.canon-cna.com/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_mg_series/pixma_mg3650.html?type=drivers&language=&os=linux)